# Open-source mock location Android app?

Tags: android, open-source, privacy, gps

Is there an open-source mock location Android app (e.g., on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/))?

Comment: You can find several candidates in my corresponding app listing for [Fake Location](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_sharefake#group_566) – watch out for the icons of F-Droid and IzzyOnDroid as well as for links to Github & Co. // If you need some specific features, please **[edit]** your question and elaborate. Currently it's a bit vague ;)

Comment: @Izzy Vague in what sense? Thanks for the Izzysoft link.

Comment: Vague in the sense of what features you need. Some of those mock location tools let you only specify a fixed locations, others offer random location, nex offer moving location (you specify the start, and the mock location moves relative to your real location), etc. Some of the apps are satisfied with using some "developer settings", others might require root. Some might come free-of-charge, others may need payment if you don't want to compile yourself (this is the "general FOSS part; not that I know that many FOSS mock-apps). And so on ;)

Answer (score 2):

[FakeTraveler](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/cl.coders.faketraveler/) is on F-Droid; [source code](https://github.com/mcastillof/FakeTraveler).
So is [Private Location](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.wesaphzt.privatelocation/); [source code](https://github.com/wesaphzt/privatelocation).

<sup>tip: [Izzy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83054/open-source-mock-location-android-app?noredirect=1#comment102504_83054) of [Izzysoft.de](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_sharefake#group_566)</sup>